# Error SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat

I have to enter the date in sqlite db. I get error, I do not understand why. can someone help me?

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy-MM-dd" );
String strDate = sdf.format( dateAndTime );
cv.put(MyTable.DATE, strDate);
```

this is the error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at java.text.DateFormat.format(DateFormat.java:361)
    at java.text.Format.format(Format.java:93)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at java.text.DateFormat.format(DateFormat.java:361)
    at java.text.Format.format(Format.java:93)
```

this is my datePicker:

```
public void chooseDate(View v) {
new DatePickerDialog(Movimenti.this, d,
                      dateAndTime.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                      dateAndTime.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                      dateAndTime.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))
  .show();}

private void updateLabel() {
  mDataScelta.setText(fmtDateAndTime
                          .format(dateAndTime.getTime()));
}
DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener d=new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                      int dayOfMonth) {
  dateAndTime.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
  dateAndTime.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
  dateAndTime.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
  updateLabel();
}
};
```

Comment: **this is the error:**

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at java.text.DateFormat.format(DateFormat.java:361)
at java.text.Format.format(Format.java:93)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at java.text.DateFormat.format(DateFormat.java:361)
at java.text.Format.format(Format.java:93)

Comment: You shold edit your question, not add error details as comments

Comment: I suspect your `dateAnndTime` variable contains something not matching specified format.

Comment: I entered my datepicker

Answer (score 0):

The format method accepts instance of Date object. And it seems like your 'dateAndTime' variable is not holding an instance of the Date object.

Comment: Aparently `dateAndTime` is of type `Calendar`.

Comment: is true of type Calendar. how do I change it??
DateFormat fmtDateAndTime=DateFormat.getDateInstance();  
  Calendar dateAndTime=Calendar.getInstance();

Comment: Date dateAndTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that `Calendar.getInstance()` will give you a calendar with the date set to the current instant.

If you got the date through a dialog and set it to `dateAndTime` which as far as I understood is a calendar object, you should better call  `dateAndTime.getTime().getTime()` to get the time in milliseconds (the first `getTime()` returns the date object and, the second returns the milliseconds time from the date), and then you pass the date in milliseconds to the `format` method.